# Client side form post on Webforms application

Tags: asp.net, jquery, post, webforms, dotnetnuke

I find myself in a bit of a jam. I am using the CMS DotNetNuke which is a webforms based application and I find myself required to create a credit card payment page which can not allow for data to be passed to the server. My first though was 'AJAX' so I wrote a POST call only to discover that the provider does not have cross origin policy implemented.... Implementation of cross origin request will probably take a while for the company to implement so I am left wondering what other client side posting options?

I have seen there is postbackURL option on asp.net buttons but I am not sure how I might define the specific fields for the post to use since I can not wrap the fields in a form tag.

Comment: Confused by "client side form post" and "I can not wrap the fields in a form tag". There is no form tag on the page? If there is, you can change the action to the secure server you need to post to, via javascript.

Comment: May be do ajax POST to your page which in turn will do the direct POST.  Once done convert response to json and post it back to callee page.  What's the API of that company?  OData, WebApi or what?

Comment: @Nickolodeon wouldn't that pass the data to his server, which is what he doesn't want? ..I'm guessing for PCI compliance reasons?

Comment: MikeSmithDev, may be that's the case.  It would be nice for author to clatify what's the problem with https'ing it to his server.

Comment: Wouldn't changing the postbackURL to the other site also trigger a cross-domain posting concern anyway?
When you say data cannot be passed to the server - I'm not being smart but are you 100% certain this is an ironclad requirement? I have worked with a fair few CC providers that, before the recent ubiquity of ajax, worked solely on you posting the data back to your own server (using https of course) and then making a cross-domain HTTPWebRequest(again over https)...as long as you don't store any data you should be able to do this....who is the CC provider as a matter of interest?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. Due to PCI compliance issues I can not pass data to the server. @MikeSmithDev dotnetnuke has a main form but does not allow the use of nested form tags, it causes the page to error. So it would believe that a submit button in this situation would post all fields found within the main form tag.

Comment: @StephenByrne this what the provider told me. "If the card data transits your machines or network you are obliged to conform to the PCI DSS." The company is called DeepCoveLabs

Comment: So it sounds like I can only wait until they add 'Access-Allow-Origin: *'

Comment: @Mark - sounds like it. They need to provide you with a way of posting this data to them without ever handling it yourself - either by hosting the data entry page themselves and giving your site a callback, or by allowing ajax. Both of these should be minimum features for payment gateways nowadays...

Comment: @StephenByrne yes if it posts back to your server, you will have to deal with PCI compliance people, even if you don't save the data. I recently went through this with them.

Comment: @All - sorry I had this in the back of my mind for a few days.
The PCI DSS clearly states :*"The PCI DSS applies to all entities that store, process, and/or transmit cardholder data."*
Therefore - if you are transmitting customer credit card details in any way shape or form, from client or server side, you are already required to be compliant. Might as well be hung for a lamb as for a goat in this case, and do the posting from your server side.
Reference: [https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI%20SSC%20Quick%20Reference%20Guide.pdf]